# How to align div class "gs" and div class "fl" in same line and in center

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to design Google search page and facing some problems.

I have completed almost every thing but got stuck in aligning "Google Search" button and "I am feeling Lucky button" in line and in center below search bar.

Below is my HTML and CSS for entire layout.

```css
body,a{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.i{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 135px;
}

nav{
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.sb input{
  border-radius: 25px ;
  border: 0.5px solid ;
  height: 40px;
  width: 480px;
}


.foo{
  font-size: medium;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
      <a href="image.html">Google Image Search </a>
      <a  href="advance.html">Advance Search</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<img src="image.png" class="i">


<form action="https://google.com/search" class="f">
  <div class="sb">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="foo">
  </div>
  <div class="gs">
      <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
  </div>
</form>
<div class="fl">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">
      <button>I am feeling lucky</button> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is my output: http://jsfiddle.net/zqwmogvd/#&togetherjs=Rd6Qeg60cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. I would wrap the two buttons in a parent div with a classname `buttons-wrap` or any class name of my choosing:

```
    <form action="https://google.com/search" class="f">
      <div class="sb">
        <input type="text" name="q" class="foo">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons-wrap">
        <div class="gs">
          <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
        </div>
        <div class="fl">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">
            <button>I am feeling lucky</button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I would then reference the `.buttons-wrap` class in CSS and use flexbox to center it:

```
.buttons-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

If you don't know flexbox, you can also use the following:

```
.buttons-wrap>div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px
}
```

`>` selects the children elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  margin-top:10px
}
```

`flex` is the value of css display. By using `display:flex` in parent elements, child elements automatically align like columns or rows with auto width and auto height.

The CSS `justify-content` property defines how the browser distributes space between and around content items along the main-axis of a flex container.